# Constrain camera parented to mesh in Blender Game Engine

Tags: game-engine, camera

In the attached blend-file, you will see that I have parented a camera to a (slightly edited cube) mesh to simulate first-person movement along a distorted plane mesh (sort of a test landscape). With sensors and actuators, I use the mouse to turn the player left and right, the W-A-S-D keys to move the player, and the mouse to turn the camera up and down. The player is also constrained to remain perpendicular to the slope of the landscape with an always sensor and a corresponding constraint.

If you play the game in camera view (just hit P in the attached file), you will see the problem: the camera wobbles horribly as the player moves, producing a nauseating effect. I cannot use sensors/actuators nor constraints (in the properties panel) to limit the rotation of the camera around its Y axis, so that it does not wobble with the player.

I would appreciate your kind assistance.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you simply remove the constraints that force it to be perpendicular to the floor? That is what seems to cause the trouble. It is also not "natural" behavior in the real world, us humans don't walk perpendicular to particular ground slope at one point, we always keep mostly upright in the direction of gravity

Comment: Deactivating the Always sensor (i.e. removing the constraint that forces the "player" cube to be perpendicular to the floor) does indeed remove the camera wobble BUT it creates another problem: If the player cube moves (by pressing the W key) towards the ground (not parallel to it), when you stop pressing the W key, there is an annoying backwards bump when you stop pressing the W key. This effect is particularly annoying when climbing up a slope: The player slides backwards for a second before stopping. I could not make this stop e.g. by tinkering with friction.

Comment: More generally, it SHOULD be possible for a player to move perpendicularly to the floor, e.g. this is exactly what a car would do: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Nykpo1AJPE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Nykpo1AJPE).

Comment: BTW thank you for taking the time to try to help me!

Comment: I found a way to reduce this backward move, when moving up a slope (or into the ground): Increase gravity, e.g. to 100.

I am still looking for an answer to my original question: Is it possible to constrain the camera movement, despite the fact that it is parented to the cube?